# Submenu doesn't highlight to full width on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

> Description: It's a static front page of the website:
>
> Problem: I have written the following code, all works fine except the submenu doesn't highlight well(not full width)

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```js
$('.nav li > .sub-menu').parent().hover(function() {
  var submenu = $(this).children('.sub-menu');
  if ($(submenu).is(':hidden')) {
    $(submenu).slideDown('slow');
  } else {
    $(submenu).slideUp('slow');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

header {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

header .row,
footer .row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav li {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: black;
  width: auto;
}

.nav>li {
  float: left;
}

.nav .sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 0.5em 2em 0.5em 0.75em;
}

.sub-menu>li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.sub-menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover {
  background: #e3e3e3;
}

header h1 {
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 0;
}

header nav {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow: visible;
}

header p {
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.jumbotron {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url('https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-4/jumbotron.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 500px;
  text-shadow: 0.25px 0.25px 0.25px #000000;
  z-index: -9999;
}

.jumbotron h2 {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.jumbotron h3 {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

section .row img {
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.col-md-6 {
  margin: 0 0 30px;
}

.btn.btn-primary {
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 0px;
  color: #fbd1d5;
  text-shadow: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s, height 2s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 5s;
}

.btn.btn-primary:hover {
  width: 70px;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 22.5px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #fbd1d5;
}

.btn-secondary {
  background-color: #E8DFE0;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0 0 30px;
}

section .col-sm-6 img {
  border-radius: 6px;
}

section .col-sm-6 img:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

footer {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

footer .col-sm-8 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

footer ul {
  list-style: none;
}

footer li img {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Skillfair</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <header class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h1 class="col-sm-4">Skillfair</h1>
      <nav class="col-sm-8 text-right">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li>
            <a href="#offers">OFFERS</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a>buy 1 get 1</a></li>
              <li><a>buy 2 get 2</a></li>
              <li><a>buy 3 get 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#catalogue">CATALOGUE</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center">
        <h2>Homemade Goods</h2>
        <h3>This Year's Best</h3>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">See all</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <figure class="col-sm-6">
        <p>kitchen</p>
        <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-4/kitchen.jpg" />
      </figure>
      <figure class="col-sm-6">
        <p>woodwork</p>
        <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-4/woodwork.jpg" />
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <figure class="col-sm-6">
        <p>gifts</p>
        <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-4/gifts.jpg" />
      </figure>
      <figure class="col-sm-6">
        <p>antiques</p>
        <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-4/antique.jpg" />
      </figure>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <p class="col-sm-4">
        &copy; 2017 Skillfair
      </p>
      <ul class="col-sm-8">
        <li class="col-sm-1"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-4/twitter.svg"></li>
        <li class="col-sm-1"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-4/facebook.svg"></li>
        <li class="col-sm-1"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-4/instagram.svg"></li>
        <li class="col-md-1"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-4/medium.svg"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How would you like to see the submenu?

Comment: I want the submenu highlight on mouse hover to its full width and above the background image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.nav .sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    // padding: 0.5em 2em 0.5em 0.75em; // remove this
    padding: 0px;
}



.sub-menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    width: auto;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    // padding: 10px 0; // remove this
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo have given padding for `.sub-menu` which is the space after the menu buttons and  gave the hover effect to the anchor tag in it which does not include the space mentioned above. Try shifting the padding from the parent to child,

```
.nav .sub-menu,
.nav .sub-menu li {
  padding: 0;
}
.sub-menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em 2em 0.5em 0.75em;
}
```